# Webpage cannot be found for image while displaying image from server

Tags: html, image, jsp, href

I am uploading my image in below path and trying to display the same with  tag .I am able to upload image in server but it shows web page cannot be found while displaying.

I am uploading file in below path

```
filePath = "/data/tms/IBM/WebSphere/images/upload/";
```

and accessing as below

```
<img src="/data/tms/IBM/WebSphere/images/upload/myimage.gif"
```

also accessing as below which shows same error

```
<a href="./upload/myimage.gif" target="_blank">
```

Please help me how can i display in my html page.

I could display image from below path without any issues.

```
<img src="css/logo_one.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `<img src="css/logo_one.gif" />` worked for you, I can only guess that the `images` folder is a sibling of `css` folder mentioned above.

So try following

```
<img src="images/upload/myimage.gif" />
```

There is a high chance that your url is malformed.
Other possibilities that can't be ruled out is that, you may not have correct permissions set on the respective file.

Comment: No, it does not work for me. I am using <a href="./upload/myimage.gif" target="_blank"> as link which also shows error

Comment: That the period `(.)` in the `"./"` wont work, since it is supposed to traverse directory on the server side, and not on client side If I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access/serve the image outside the Web-application in this way.

To access the image via the browser/HTML - it should be served via the application or server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve your image from the server using a back-end programming language like PHP. It looks like you've created your database already with assigned credentials, now you just need to retrieve the data using PHP and MySQL or any other database language you prefer. Remember to also connect your site with the database.